Android: What is "build Dsl" and where is it located?
In gradle.properties I have this line
android.defaults.buildfeatures.buildconfig=true

In Build output I see this warning:

The option setting 'android.defaults.buildfeatures.buildconfig=true'
is deprecated.

I tried to resolve this warning in Android Studio via Refactor > Migrate BuildConfig to Gradle Build Files

The line android.defaults.buildfeatures.buildconfig=true gets removed from gradle.properties, but no other project files are modified.
Question:  What is "build Dsl" and where is it located?

DSL = Dynamic Scripting Language which mean the gradle config now uses Kotlin Script and the Gradle build config is now named build.gradle.kts instead of the previously used build.gradle.

As per this commit, the plan to remove the flag
android.defaults.buildfeatures.buildconfig=true

When you click on the Android Studio suggestion, it should ideally add the new way as well, but I'm assuming they don't do it, because people might have a different gradle structure overally
What you can do is, simple go to your app level build.gradle.kts file, and add the following
android {
    // ... Other code
    
    buildFeatures {
       buildConfig = true
    }
}


I'm assuming you have a Gradle version above 8, so these changes are mentioned here
If you're curious about the reason behind the removal, here's a detailed post on updating to Flamingo
